# Are there typescript types for Twilio's statusCallbackEvent?

Tags: typescript, twilio

I initiated my project using `https://www.twilio.com/docs/labs/serverless-toolkit/guides/typescript` with the `--typescript` option.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/labs/serverless-toolkit/guides/typescript

I setup a handler to handle statusCallback events from my conference:

```
// Imports global types
import "@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types";
// Fetches specific types
import {
  Context,
  ServerlessCallback,
  ServerlessFunctionSignature,
} from "@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types/types";
import req from "@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types/types";

let twilioClient: import("twilio/lib/rest/Twilio");

export const handler: ServerlessFunctionSignature = async function (
  context: Context,
  event: any, // LOOKING FOR TYPES FOR THIS OBJECT!!! :)
  callback: ServerlessCallback
) {
  twilioClient = context.getTwilioClient();

  try {
    const {
      StatusCallbackEvent,
      CallSid,
      FriendlyName: roomId,
      Timestamp,
    } = event;

    switch (StatusCallbackEvent) {
      case "participant-join": {
        console.log("participant-join");
        // Process event...
        break;
      }
      case "conference-end": {
        console.log("conference-end");
        // Process event...
        break;
      }
      default: {
        break;
      }
    }

    return callback(null);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return callback(err);
  }
};
```

I am wondering if there are types available for the `event` object in this case?  I can't seem to find them in the `twilio/lib` module either.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist (and [Serverless Toolkit](https://github.com/twilio-labs/serverless-toolkit/) maintainer) here.

We do not have types for the various requests that can end up as the `event` object, I'm afraid.

If you are looking to receive status callbacks for calls then the parameters you will receive are a combination of the [request parameters in every call webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#request-parameters) and the [extra parameters for a call status callback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#statuscallbackevent).

We do accept contributions to the Serverless Toolkit if you do create types and want to contribute them to the [serverless-runtime-types package](https://github.com/twilio-labs/serverless-toolkit/tree/main/packages/serverless-runtime-types) for others to use.

Comment: Okay, thank you!  I'll have a crack at it! :)